# Recursively creating strings from 2 dimensional character array

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

I need to create all possible strings from a 2d-array so that the first character comes from `charArray[0]`, the second character comes from `charArray[1]`...and the final character comes from the `charArray[keyLength-1]`.

Example:

***input:***

```
char[][] charArray =  
{{'m','M','L','S','X'}
 {'e','E','o','N','Z'}
 {'o','G','F','r','Y'}
 {'D','H','I','J','w'}};
```

***output:***

```
{meoD, meoH, meoI,..., XZYJ, XZYw}  //in an Array or ArrayList
```

I had a working solution that builts a tree with each character in `charArray[0]` as a root and it did a depth first string construction, but the JVM ran out of memory for charArray lengths less than 12.  I would normally take an iterative approach, but the charArray length (i.e. key string length) is decided at runtime and I would like to find a more complete solution than writing a switch statement on the key string length and manually writing out loops for a finite number of key string lengths.

I've been stuck on this small section of my program for longer than I'd like to admit, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you put your code here.

Comment: even if charArray is determined at run time you have .length field for arrays

Comment: @hhafeez  Yes but the problem comes from trying to handle the characters in the array.  The best iterative solution I can figure out would require the line inside the final nested loop to look like:           keyArrayList.add(charArray[0].charAt(a)+charArray[1].charAt(b)+....+charArray(keyLength-1).charAt(x).  That is to say I would need to manually write a charAt statement for each charArray[i].  This obviously presents a problem if the length of charArray varies greatly.  If you can think of a different way to do it I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: @Leozeo.  I would be happy to elaborate on anything to make things clearer, but my program is around 1000 lines total, so posting the entire things seems a little like overkill.  In terms of code for a recursive algorithm, I'm afraid that visualizing recurisve design has always been a weakpoint for me, so I came here in hopes of finding someone that could give me some pointers.  The purpose of the program is to solve a repeating-key XOR cipher given only the encrypted base 64 string.  In general terms here is what my program does: (in next comment)

Comment: @Leozeo.  **1.** Detect the most likely key lengths using Hamming Distance, Index of Coincidence, trigrams, and the greatest common divisors of these tests.  **2.** Break the input string into blocks of size "key length".  **3.**  Rearange the blocks so that I have a block with all the first characters of each block, a block with all the second characters of each block, and so on.  **4.**  Solve each block as a single-character XOR.  **5.** For each block, the character that scores best using a chi squared character frequency analysis is most likely the key for that block.

Comment: I thought you wanted an algorithmic solution rather than analytical solution. I don't understand why you need that much mathematical rigour. The problem can be solved without Hamming and chi square etc.

Comment: @mjf If your requirement is what you stated then I am afraid you are not on right track to solve the problem and doing the stuff that has nothing to do with problem

Comment: @hhafeez  I don't mean to be obtuse, but could you please elaborate?  It is likely that I am over thinking things over haven't explained what I'm trying to do properly.  My posted question is in regards to generating all the possible best scoring keys (which would be a subset of 5 above).  I am assembling the best scoring characters for each block such that I am generating a key that includes all the best scoring characters, a key that includes all the second best scoring characters, etc.  However, I have found that sometimes the correct key consists of characters...

Comment: @hhafeez ..from the best scoring character key and (e.g.) the fifth best scoring character key.  Basically, the plain text for the correct characters for the key are not always scoring the highest on the chi squared test.  While my chi squared may be flawed, I think the "error" comes from the fact that during this stage the chi squared is only looking at the subset of the input string that corresponds to a single character in the key.  I have tried using different frequency tables for how often each character appears in an english language string without any improvement.

Comment: @mjf I meant you are not clearly isolating the problem and mixing one problem with other. Here is what I understood that you want to list all combination of characters where each character in the combination belongs to exatctly one row

Comment: given the input { M, K} {N,P} you want the output {MN,MP,KN,KP}. right?

Comment: @hhafeez  ^ this is correct.  I originally tried to keep the problem as concise as possible to avoid unneccesary details, but I got off on a tangent when Leozeo asked for details about the program.  Sorry.  I believe you understand the problem.

Comment: okay then it has nothing to do with hamming and chi and can be solved iteratively.

Comment: How can that be done without explicitly writing a loop for each charArray[i]?  The problem is if I do that, then I would need to explicitly write a case for each possible charArray length.  I can't explicitly write loops for every possible length to infinity (even though the length is likely to never be over 40).

Comment: I have shown the solution which works for any length any size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can be solved:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Arrays2D {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //input keys

    String[][] charArray = 
        {{"m","M","L","S","X"},
         {"e","E","o","N","Z"},
         {"o","G","F","r","Y"},
         {"D","H","I","J","w"}};
    //print output
    System.out.println(findCombinations(charArray));

}

private static List<String> findCombinations(String[][] charArray) {
    List<String> prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        List<String> curr = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (i + 1 < charArray.length) {
            for (int l = 0; l < charArray[i+1].length; l++) {
                    String s = charArray[i][j] + charArray[i + 1][l];
                    curr.add(s);
                }
            }

        }
        if (prev != null && !curr.isEmpty()) {
            prev = join(prev, curr);
        }
        if (prev == null)
            prev = curr;

    }

    return prev;
}

public static List<String> join(List<String> p, List<String> q) {
    List<String> join = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String st1 : p) {
        for (String st2 : q) {

            if (st1.substring(st1.length() - 1).equals(st2.substring(0, 1))) {
                String s = st1 + st2;
                s = s.replaceFirst(st1.substring(st1.length() - 1), "");
                join.add(s);
            }

        }
    }

    return join;
}
}
```

I have checked and it correctly generating the combinations. You can run and see the output.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much for taking the time to figure this out. If you don't mind, could you please help me understand the IF section of your join method.  It still seems like magic to me.

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this in the future:  Since "[" and "]" are possible characters in charArray, I found that I need additional if statements inside the If statement in join() in order to handle them separately.  i.e.                                      if(st1.substring(st1.length() - 1).equals("[")){  
  s = s.replaceFirst("\\[", "");
}
else if(st1.substring(st1.length() - 1).equals("]")){  
    s = s.replaceFirst("\\]", "");
}
else{
           s = s.replaceFirst(st1.substring(st1.length() - 1), "");
}
join.add(s);             


sorry for the formatting

Comment: yes I can explain that too. In the mean time, would you accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: The if statement is the actual condition for joining two elements of arrary. This says that if ending character of str1 equals the first character of str2 then they should be joined. i.e "cs","st" shuld be joined and after joining we I toss out the joining character s one time . so after joining cs and sc i should have "cst".